# Why does $r=e^{-r}/0.05$ diverge with iteration?

Tags: convergence-divergence, nonlinear-system

I have the following nonlinear equation which I want to solve (the answer is about 2.205):

$r=e^{-r}/0.05$

I'd like to understand why the equation above will only converge (using iteration) if I put it in the following form:

$r=-\ln(r*0.05)$

I'm in an engineering program and I've noticed other equations which involve logs where iteration works to find an answer. I think I can use iteration when the equation involves logs, but I'd like to be sure.

To be clear, when I refer to iteration I mean:

1. Making a guess for the value of r.
2. Subbing into the RHS and computing.
3. Use the found value and sub into the RHS again.
4. Continue until value converges.

Comment: starting at r=1 seems to work for me. After 6-8 iterations i get to 2.2 which makes the absolute error so small as one in a million

Comment: For many iterative methods if they converge can depend on initial value. You may need to do restarts with new better guesses to have convergence.

Comment: @mathreadler can you confirm that you get the solution to converge using the first equation I've provided (with the exponential form)?

Comment: @mathreadler I think there is a communication error, or I'm misunderstanding something. I don't believe the equation converges using iteration when it is in the exponential form.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, i misread the question. I thought you were iterating the log one. The solution is closer to 2.205 and not 2.05 which is what I thought you missed on first.

Comment: My mistake, that is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of your method of iteration as follows. Imagine that you're plotting the RHS and the LHS as two separate functions, $f(r) = r$ and $g(r) = e^{-r} / 0.05$. The solution for $r = e^{-r}/0.05$, graphically, is all values of $r$ where $f$ and $g$ intersect on a plot with $r$ on the $x$-axis.

The iteration process then looks something like this:
[image: Exponential Form of Iteration]

Once you transform the equation, you end up with an iteration process that looks like this:
[image: Log form of the equation]

As you can see, the rate at which the equation is changing plays a big role in whether it converges or not. In general, if a function $f(r)$ changes at some rate $f'(r)$, then $\ln(f(r))$ changes much more slowly at $\frac{d}{dr}\ln(f(r)) = \frac{1}{f(r)} \cdot f'(r)$.

If you want a much more reliable, but still relatively each method to implement, consider using [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

EDIT: Here's how to solve the non-linear equation using Newton's method.

For Newton's, you want an equation of the form $f(r) = 0$. Here, we have $f(r) = e^{-r}/0.05 - r$, which implies that $f'(r) = -e^{-r}/0.05 - 1$. Given some initial guess $r_0$, the next guess in the iteration is gotten by:
$$ r_{i + 1} = r_i - \frac{f(r_i)}{f'(r_i)} $$
Using Newton's method, here's what my iterations look like:
\begin{array}{c | c}
  i & r_i\\
  \hline
  0 & 1 \\ 
  1 & 1.7607 \\ 
  2 & 2.1387 \\ 
  3 & 2.2035 \\ 
  4 & 2.2050 \\ 
  5 & 2.2050 \\ 
\end{array}

Comment: Newton's method doesn't seem to work for the exponential form either. I am trying it now with a initial value of 1 and the value diverges.

Comment: I managed to get it to converge using Newton's. See my updated answer for what I did :)

Comment: I did not put it in the 0 form. I see my error. Thank you :). It works for both equation forms.

Answer (score 1):

If the slopes are too great at the point of intersection, iteration will not converge to the point of intersection.

Consider this picture.

[image]

In order for this itterative method to converge the slope of your function must be between $+1$ and $-1$ at the point of intersection.

But when you manipulate the equation

$r = -\ln (0.05r)$ now you have a function with a flat enough slope.

Comment: My intuition is that it is generally better to have the equation in a log form for using the iteration method. Is that a reasonable generalization?

Comment: @Klik No, the point is exactly what the answer said, it depends on the magnitude of the slope at the intersection point.  But if your original function has slope of magnitude $> 1$, then the inverse function will have slope of magnitude $< 1$.  Using this, it's easy to come up with examples where an exponential iteration converges but the corresponding logarithmic iteration diverges - for example, $x = e^{-x}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You have several graphical answers ready. I will instead of an answer offer a fix for the problem by *smoothing* the iteration. Smoothing is a very useful concept in very many areas of applied mathematics.

Consider an iteration with memory $$r_{n+1} = 0.5r_n + 0.5 \exp(-r_n)/0.05$$Which remembers 50% of the previous value and only adds 50% of the new value.

[image]

While first hopping to 4 we get a quite quick convergence when starting at $r_1=1$.

Comment: Ouu. Interesting. A new numerical method for me :D.

Comment: This is an excellent method, it works nicely and it's very easy to remember!

Comment: And you can combine it with any other iterative scheme if you want. Or with physics differential equations, or controlling quadcopters, or statistics, or... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because, if you set $f(r)=e^{-r}/0.05$, and $r_0$ is the solution, $r_0\approx 2.05$, you have $f'(r_0)=-e^{-r}/0.05=-r_0\approx -2.05$ and $|f'(r_0)|\gt 1$.

Now note how the function $f$ behaves in the neigbourhood of $r_0$: $f(r)-f(r_0)=(r-r_0)f'(\xi)$ (mean value theorem), where $\xi$ is between $r$ and $r_0$, so the "distance" between $f(r)$ and $f(r_0)$ equals the "distance" of $r$ to $r_0$ multiplied by something close to $f'(r_0)$, which is greater than $1$ in module. In other words, the iteration "expands" the small intervals around $r_0$.

Go to the inverse function $f^{-1}(r)=-\log(0.05r)$ and the derivative is the reciprocal of the derivative we got before, i.e. it is $((f^{-1})'(r_0)=-\frac{1}{r_0}\approx -\frac{1}{2.05}$, and this is $\lt 1$ in module. By the same logic, we conclude that $f^{-1}$ is a *contraction* of small intervals around $r_0$. It is intuitively clear (and can be proven strictly) that, at least when you start in one such small interval, your sequence will converge.